# Spring Boot - Autowired MongoClient

Tags: spring, spring-boot, autowired

I got pretty confused now, I would like to use @Autowired MongoClient attribute in one of my Controller classes, but without success. The tricky part of it is that @Autowired is working from my @RestController.

```
@RestController
public final class WebController {

  /** mongoClient */
  @Autowired
  private MongoClient mongoClient; <- here it's working ...
...
}
```

but:

```
@Controller
public final class MongoUsersDAO {

  /** mongoClient */
  @Autowired
  private MongoClient mongoClient; <- not working ...
...
}
```

here I get null.

I do not think that the problem would be the component scan while my @SpringBootApplication is located at **x.y.z**, my @RestController at **x.y.z.t** and my @Controller at **x.y.z.k** packages, hence booth of them should be scanned by Spring.
(The Eclipse also marks my @Controller as a Spring class)

What else could be the problem then ?

Note:
If I add this to my @Controller it's working fine but the @Autowired still wount work:

```
@PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    System.out.println("INIT");
  }
```

Note: In the mentioned MongoUsersDAO the autowired thing is not working at all, I've tried to get a simple property as well from the application.properties, without success.

Comment: strange. Any logs ? any where you called new MongoUsersDAO() ? . Strangely why DAO class is annotated with @Controller ?

Comment: I've tried to annotate it with service, component, etc. as well. The new mongoUsersDAO() is called inside the WebController when a new request comes. (it's a test implementation yet)

Comment: That's the problem . Don't call new mongoUserdDao(). If you do that autowiring won't happen.

Comment: Why? If I would like to use it I have to instanciate it somehow, not ?

Comment: There is already a single instance available through `@Service` or `@Component` of DAO class why you want to instantiate it again ? if you do it then autowiring will not happen

Comment: Barath, could you write it as an answer, then I could accept it ;) Thank you so much :)

Comment: Answer is already there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem occured because you have called `new MongoUserDAO()` inside your `WebController` class as you mentioned in the comment below your question. If you instantiate an object by hand and you have field annotated with `@Autowired` then this field won't be instantiated with expected instance.

Inject `MongoUsersDAO` directly to your `WebController` class as shown below, Spring will handle injecting `MongoClient` to `MongoUserDAO` class for you.

**WebController** :

```
@RestController
public final class WebController {

    /** Service/Repository class*/
    @Autowired
    private MongoUsersDAO dao; 

    @GetMapping("/all")
    public String getAll(){
        dao.callSomeMethod();
     }
}
```

**MongoUsersDAO**:

```
@Repository
public final class MongoUsersDAO {

  /** mongoClient */
  @Autowired
  private MongoClient mongoClient; 
...
}
```

Comment: Thank you again :)